# Having trouble adding an item to an array through a function (C)

Tags: c, function, pointers, crash, scanf

So I'm pretty new to programming and I can be kind of a mess sometimes so bear with me please.

I'm trying to make a program that handles two different arrays, and I tried to make a function that adds an item to either, however I'm having a bit of trouble, the program goes something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int **queue, int *cont, int *item); //the idea is to 
   // call the array i want to add the item to, 
   // the counter for that respective array, and the scanned 
   // item to be added

void instructions();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i=0, j=0;                       //counters for each array
    int value;                          //scanned value to insert
    int op;
    int *queue1[10], *queue2[10];       //the arrays i'm going to use
    while (op!=0){
        instructions();
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch(op) {
        case 1:
            printf("You've chosen to enqueue an item, please insert the item you want to add to the array:\n" );
            scanf("%d", &value);
            insert(queue1,&i,&value); //here's the case for adding 
               // an item to array one, i called the array, its 
               //counter and the value i want to insert
            break;
        default :
            if (op!=0)
            printf("Invalid Option.\n" );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void insert(int **queue, int *count, int *item){
    if(*count==9){
        printf("You can't add more items.");
        }else{
        *queue[*count]=item;
        *count=(*count+1);
    }
}

void instructions(){
    printf("What function do you want to use?\n1)Insert Queue 1.\n2)Remove Queue 1.\n3)Print Queue 1.\n4)Insert Queue 2.\n5)Remove Queue 2.\n6)Insert Queue 2.\n0)Exit.\n");
}
```

As you can see, the program is a mess of pointers and stuff, I looked everywhere, I read pages and pages about functions, but nowhere could I find something to help me with what I want, after applying what I thought I had learned, this is the mess that I ended up with. The counter seems to work fine and increase each time the function is used which is what I wanted, however when I tried putting a `printf("%d\n", queue1[0]);` after the instructions function to show me if the value had indeed been inserted into the array, it showed some pretty weird number which doesn't even look like an address to me, and to top it all off, after using the function about **3** times to **"add"** random numbers to the array, the program just crashes.

So if someone could help me, a complete rookie, understand what I'm doing wrong so I can fix this mess I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do not allocate any memory for your "queue" elements.

```
insert(queue1,&i,&value);
```

With `i` and `value` being local variables of type `int` you will use the same memory location again and again when you fill pointers in your array.

```
void insert(int **queue, int *count, int *item){
    if(*count==9){
        printf("You can't add more items.");
    }else{
        *queue[*count]=item;
        *count=(*count+1);
    }
}
```

In this function you receive the addresses to the local variables from the caller.

When you assign `item` to an element of your array, it will point to `value` from caller function.
And you would fill *every* element of the array with the same address.

Another problem:

`queue1` is not initialized and contains 10 random addresses.

```
*queue[*count]=item;
```

Here you dereference those addresses causing your crash.

You need to allocate memory for each new element.

```
int *queue1[10];
...
insert(queue1, &i, value);
...
void insert(int **arr, int *count, int value){
    if(*count==9){
        printf("You can't add more items.");
    }else{
        int *item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
        if (item != NULL)
        {
            *item = value;
            arr[*count]=item;
            *count=(*count+1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("memory allocation error\n");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or...

As you use an array, you might just store the value directly without any allocation

```
int queue1[10];
...
insert(queue1, &i, value);
...
void insert(int *arr, int *count, int item){
    if(*count==9){
        printf("You can't add more items.");
    }else{
        arr[*count]=item;
        *count=(*count+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This `*arr[*count]= ...` ought to be `arr[*count]=...`.

Comment: Yes, I've just seen that this was the main reason for the crash in the question. Thanks for the hint.